# Very noisy indoor scene mystery

Tags: cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction

I'm working on a indoor scene in Cycles Blender 2.90 with the Nishita sky as light source coming trough the windows.

For the glass material I used Blender Guru's glass hack, but I'm sure the glass isn't the problem since I get the same noise without the windows in the scene.

I do use portals for the windows and I have even cranked the samples up to 4000, still I get a lot of noise.

I do not want to use the denoiser since I think it removes to much details and I get artifacts with this level of noise.

I would really appreciate if someone could [have a look at my scene](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-UyOxwzyNFsjxYbyqyNz8rD64zIr5Obd).

This is how noisy my scene look with 2000 samples (this images is 50%, look even noisier at 100%

[image]

Comment: Looks about right. You can render passes and use denoising only on the passes you need it on. If this is unusual, how noisy are your usual interior scenes?

Comment: The intel denoiser actually works very well at preserving details if you turn on the denoising data pass in passes.

Comment: my usual interior renders are not this noisy at all. I tried the intel denoising but I kind of got a slight oil painting effect